# Include pictures in JS bundle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, bundle, rollup

My case is the following :

I create a components library for React. So I have a package (bundled with Rollup) that include some pictures (For now only a GIF picture that is used in a component).

The component that use my picture is like this :

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import ui_spinner from '../../../assets/ui_progress.gif';

/**
 * CircularSpinner
 * Add a spinner when the user needs to wait
 */
class CircularSpinner extends React.PureComponent {
  static propTypes = {
    /** Width of the component */
    width: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.number]),
    /** Height of the component */
    height: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.number]),
    /** Style of the component (overload existing properties) */
    style: PropTypes.object,
  }

  static defaultProps = {
    width: 128,
    height: 128,
    style: {},
  }

  render() {
    const { style, width, height } = this.props;

    return (
      <img src={ui_spinner} width={width} height={height} style={style} alt="ui_progress" aria-busy="true" />
    );
  }
}

export default CircularSpinner;
```

When I built it, it's OK.

Now I create a React application with create-react-app and I want to test my components library. To do this, I use `npm link` (To avoid to push deploy my npm package). My components are OK in my testing application but the picture (the GIF in my CircularSpinner component) is not displayed.

**So my question is the following : How to include some assets in a JS bundle with Rollup ? My working approach is correct ?**

My Rollup config is the following :

```
import { uglify } from 'rollup-plugin-uglify'
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel'
import url from 'rollup-plugin-url'

const config = {
  input: 'src/index.js',
  external: ['react'],
  output: {
      format: 'umd',
      name: 'react-components',
      globals: {
          react: "React"
      }
  },
  plugins: [
    babel({
      exclude: "node_modules/**"
    }),
    uglify(),
    url(),
  ]
}
export default config
```

I build with `rollup -c -o dist/index.js`.

And the dist folder has the following content :

```
dist/
  assets
    92be5c546b4adf43.gif
  index.js
```

My component that use my picture is like this in my testing application :

`<img src="92be5c546b4adf43.gif" width="128" height="128" alt="ui_progress" aria-busy="true">`

Thanks for your help !

Damien

Comment: look at your devtools network tab - are the images trying to load? do you get a 404? what path are they trying to load from?

Comment: I get a 200 status for the URL http://localhost:3000/92be5c546b4adf43.gif. I have the feeling that my picture are not correctly exposed.

Comment: I found the solution (see my next answer), Thank you for your response !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution for this issue. This response may help someone :

I update my rollup config to use *rollup-plugin-img*. I have already used it but my configuration was not correct :

The correct config is the following :

```
import { uglify } from 'rollup-plugin-uglify'
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel'
import image from 'rollup-plugin-img'

const config = {
  input: 'src/index.js',
  external: ['react'],
  output: {
      format: 'umd',
      name: 'react-components',
      globals: {
          react: "React"
      }
  },
  plugins: [
    babel({
      exclude: "node_modules/**"
    }),
    image({
      limit: 100000,
    }),
    uglify(),
  ]
}
export default config
```

My error was that my GIF is a little big and the default limit size is 8192 bytes.
In this case, I have the following error :

```
Error: Could not load <path of image> (imported by <path of component that use image>): The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
```

When I have updated my config to increase the limit, everything is OK